# Need help to speed up this MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am a bit rusty with my SQL and some help to improve the speed of this one with some left hand joins...

```
            SELECT 
            distinct FN.field_first_name_value as "First Name", 
            LN.field_last_name_value as "Last Name",   
            u.mail,
            IFNULL(
                 (SELECT (
                    select 
                 CASE
                     WHEN status = 4 THEN "Expiring Soon" 
                     WHEN status = 3 THEN "Active Payments Complete" 
                     WHEN status = 0 THEN "Expired / Inactive"
                     WHEN status = 2 THEN "Cancelled" 
                 END AS status
                    FROM memberships smm
                    where u.uid = smm.uid
                    limit 1
                 )
                     FROM users_roles SUR1
                   WHERE SUR1.uid = u.uid
                     AND SUR1.rid = 4
                   LIMIT 1
                 )
               ,"No") AS "Paying Member",
            IFNULL(
                 (SELECT "Yes"
                      FROM users_roles SUR
                   WHERE SUR.uid = u.uid
                     AND SUR.rid = 10
                   LIMIT 1
                 )
               ,"No") AS "Newsletter Subscriber"
            FROM
            users u, 
            field_data_field_first_name FN, 
            field_data_field_last_name LN, 
            role R,
            scio_users_roles SUR
            where 
            u.uid = FN.entity_id 
            AND 
            u.uid = LN.entity_id
```

Thje query returns results as I want them, but it takes far too long. I realise I need to improve the way the query is built up but am unsure how to implement the left hand joins.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Would be better if you told us your schema and what you're trying to do (sample data and sample results) rather than us trying to reverse engineer your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisrt of all execute this statement with a EXPLAIN in the begin. See if your query is using index for all tables.

Second thing, try to use "new format" join statements, use JOIN tableA ON tableB instead tableA,tableB staments.

Check if your query is using index for all joins. The explain should bring you helpful information.